# Php Get file from root dir to another dir

Tags: php, dir, home-directory

Hi I am new in php programming and learning this i have found a small problem.
I Have directories something like this:

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/
 -practise
    + /css
    + /js
    + /images
    - /extra
      - /folder1
        - / folder1_1
            tst.php
    index.php
    navbar.php
    about.php
    blab.php
    foo.php
    lib.php
```

I have created a lib.php where in this file contain all files of `/css and /js`(jquery, w3.css,etc). And  i add this file in `tst.php` like this `include(../../../lib.php);`. when i run my tst.php file in browser, the content of lib.php execute but the files of `css and js` dont load on browser (in inspect element --> console give me error *file not found*).

How can i use my lib.php in tst.php and almost in every folder... ?

Do i use something like `$_server['something']./lib.php...` ?

here is my `lib.php`:

```
echo '<script src="js/browjs.js"></script> ';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/poperi.css">';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3.css">';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navigt.css">';
echo " this is content for check if lib.php is loaded or not";// this line show me in tst.php
```

I tried my best to explain my problem and i dont know what u need more to know about this problem...
TY in advance...

Comment: Try echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" '. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/practise/css/poperi.css">';

Comment: if i upload my site on altervista all file **from** practise folder then i have to change all my code or not ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try

```php
define( '_LIB_FILE_', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'practise' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib.php' );
```

and use the `_LIB_FILE_` constant `include_one _LIB_FILE_;`

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is your root directory `c:/xampp/htdocs/` you just append your subdir to it

LE:
so in your lib.php put these lines of code

```php
<?php
$root        = str_replace( '\\', '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] );
$current_dir = str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
$http_root   = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace( $root, '', $current_dir ) . '/';

// echo $http_root; // this will let you see what is your current http path of lib.php ex. http://localhost/practise/
// next you include your code
// BEST PRACTICE short for multiple echos
echo '<script src="', $http_root, 'js/browjs.js"></script> ';
// you could do it with concatanation
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $http_root . 'css/poperi.css">';
// string evaluation
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='{$http_root}css/w3.css'>";
// string evaluation with character escaping \"
echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$http_rootcss/navigt.css\">";

echo " this is content for check if lib.php is loaded or not";
```

in your tst.php you can now include the snippet previously mentioned, but I converted it to variable

```php
// this is called absolute path
$library_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'practise' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib.php';
include $library_file;
// or 
// include( $library_file );
// and this is relative path. meaning the file relatively to your current file
// include '../../../lib.php';
```

Comment: hi sir ty for answering but how i am say  i am new programming langs  i dont know yet how to use define.... Can u provide me another solution easy and more comfortable...

Comment: i edited my answer so maybe you can understand a little bit better, what needs to be done. also keep in mind that the $root and $current_dir varies depending on your operating system. windows has backslash \ while the rest ( I think ) normal slash /. so on win it's actually c:\xampp\htdocs\  but it works with slash as well. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, as the name implies your OS's directory separator

Comment: if i will upload this on an host will i have to change something or i wont ?

Comment: if you will use absolute path than yes $library_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'practise' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib.php';, but if you will use relative path for your file includes than no you wont because the str_replace will take care of it for you. in lib.php you wont need to change anything just the way you include lib.php so by using reltive path ../../../../lib.php you wont need to change anything

Comment: which are these absoulute path and relative path ?
is absolute path (htdocs/practise/extra/folder1/folder1_1)  or (localhost/practise/extra/folder1/folder1_1/tst.php)?
 is relative path (extra/folder1/folder1_1) ?

Comment: Absolute path in your example is c:/xampp/htdocs/practise/lib.php and relative path is ../../../lib.php in your tst.php file

Comment: it is not working on altervista  http://mywebsite.altervista.org/membri/mywebsite/css/poperi.css  i am getting like these 5 error in console. in localhost  working prefect as i aspacted

Comment: as i have seen you have a wordpress installation, so you should first check your paths. meaning that http://mywebsite.altervista.org/membri/mywebsite/ in your script should be under /public_html/membri/mywebsite/ presuming your main root in public_html